# Plone 4.2 how to make PAS cache external usera data

Tags: caching, persistence, plone

I'm implementing a PAS plugin that handles authentications against mailservers. Actually only DBMail is implemented.

I realized, that the `enumerateUsers` function from the PAS plugin is called numerous times per request and requires my plugin to open/close an SQL connections for every (subsequent) request. Of course, this is very expensive.

The connections itself are handled in a plone tool, which is able to handle multiple different mailservers and delegeates the `enumerateUsers` call to wrapper objects that represent registered servers.

My question is now, what sort of cache (OOBTree, Session?) I should use to provide a temporary local storage for repeating enumerations and avoid subsequent SQL connections?

Another idea was, to hook into the user creation process that takes place on the first login, an external user issues and completely "localize" the users.

Third idea was, to store the needed data in the specific member, if possible.

What would be best practice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd cache the query results, indeed. You need to make a decision on *how long* to cache the results, and if stored long term, how to invalidate that cache or check for changes.

There are no *best practices* for these decisions, as they depend entirely on the type of data stored and the APIs of the backends. If they support some kind of freshness query, for example, then you store everything forever and poll the backend to see if the cache needs updating.

You can start with a simple request cache; query once per request, store it *on* the request object. Your cache will automatically be invalidated at the end of the request as the request object is cleaned up, the next request will be a clean slate.

If your backend users rarely change, you can cache information for longer, in a local cache. I'd use a volatile attribute on the plugin. Any attribute starting with `_v_` is ignored by the persistence machinery. Thus, anything stored in a `_v_` volatile attribute is both thread-local and only exists for the lifetime of the process, a restart of the server clears these automatically.

At the very least you should use an `_v_` volatile attribute to store your backend SQL connections. That way they can stay open between requests, and can be re-used. Something like the following method would do nicely:

```
def _connection(self):
    # Return a backend connection
    if getattr(self, '_v_connection', None) is None:
        # Create connection here
        self._v_connection = yourdatabaseconnection
    return self._v_connection
```

You could also use a persistent attribute on your plugin to store your cache. This cache would be committed to the ZODB and persist across restarts. You then really need to work out how to invalidate the contents; store timestamps and evict data when to old, etc.

Your cache datastructure depends entirely on your application needs. If you don't persist information, a dictionary (username -> information) could be more than enough. Persisted caches could benefit from using a `OOBTree` instead of a dictionary as they reduce chances of conflicts between different threads and are more efficient when it comes to large sets of data.

Whatever you do, you do *not* need to use a Session. Sessions are prone to conflicts, do not scale well, and are in any case not the place to store a cache of this kind.

Comment: Thank you so much. I already now about the greatness of OOBTrees and use them as cache for my webmail_view. This works great. But the hint, to use the `_v_` as possibility to reuse the sql connection was not in my mind. Thanks again for this very very useful information.